# Windows ::DeleteFile() fails on non-English Windows

Tags: winapi, delete-file

Our software posts errors to an online database when users encounter errors. In reviewing the database we noticed that ::DeleteFile() occasionally fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, but only when the user is running a non-English version of Windows. Yes, strange but true! We have never had this error posted except with non-English error messages. The messages span human languages, e.g., "Toegang geweigerd," "Zugriff verweigert," "Accès refusé," "Acceso denegado," "Åtkomst nekad," "Ingen tilgang," "Käyttö estetty." etc. Never in English. Strange!

More Info: We've had these messages posted for ~40 users, we have ~3000 users, and ~80% of our customers use English versions of Windows. When it does happen to a customer, it appears to happen repeatedly (e.g., each time they use the software). The name of the file being deleted is the same regardless of the human language (i.e., the name is similar to "setup.exe"). It doesn't seem possible that the language could be coincidental.

Do you have any ideas on why DeleteFile() would occasionally return accessed denied on non-English version of Windows?

Comment: Is the name for the file (or path) that is to be deleted different per language?

Comment: The error has NOTHING to do with the language of the OS and EVERYTHING to do with the file that is being deleted. The user account that is associated with the thread that is deleting the file does not have permission to delete the file, either because it belongs to another user or to the system itself, or it resides in a folder that the deleting user does not have permission to delete from.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You also get that error when the file is read only.

Comment: @theB: good catch, I forgot about that. The documentation does say: "*If the file is a read-only file, the function fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.*"

Comment: Ton, "The name of the file being deleted is the same regardless of the human language"

Comment: The file is always stored in the same folder regardless of the human language. The file is the most recent setup.exe for our program. It is stored in a folder similar to C:\ProgramData\Company\Product that we write to frequently during program use. The user had write-rights (at least when they downloaded the updated), because we saved the file to that folder. It is possible they downloaded the update when they had admin permissions and no longer have admin permission when they run the newly installed program, but it is too coincidental that this only happen on non-English versions.

Comment: The file is an executable, right?  Does it have a manifest?  Is the program trying to delete itself?

Comment: Get one of your users to run Process Monitor and send you a log.

Comment: Perhaps some anti-malware that's more popular with your non-English customer base is holding the file open for scanning.  The usual hack is to wait a moment and retry the deletion.